# adb version says 1.0.32 but droid-explorer says its 1.0.29 and won't start

Tags: adb, droid-explorer

Using win7 64bit.

I downloaded *just* the commandline tools from developer.android.com; the zip not the installer.

I copied everything to `c:\dev\android\sdk\` and ran the SDK Manager and updated everything. When I run> `adb version` it reports a version of 1.0.32

I installed the most recent droid-explorer, using DroidExplorer.0.9.0.4.x64.Setup.zip .. during the installation it asks me to specify the android sdk directory, which it detects correctly as `c:\dev\android\sdk\`

After installation, I run droid-explorer wherein it states `adb version is 1.0.29, minimum supported version is 1.0.31` .. I cannot launch it properly.

I added `c:\dev\android\sdk\platform-tools` to the Environment Variable PATH but this did nothing.

Any insight in to why the adb version is being incorrectly reported would be appreciated. I tried copying 1.0.31 binaries overtop as well and this did not solve anything.

Thank you.